# Make 2 overlapping lines NOT look thicker

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to plot 2 squares touching eachother, but the common side line appears thicker.
How can I avoid that? (I want the linewidth to be 0.1, change it to another value won't solve my problem)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0]
x2 = [0, -1, -1, 0, 0]
y = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]

plt.plot(x1, y, 'k', linewidth = 0.1)
plt.plot(x2, y, 'k', linewidth = 0.1)
```

Here's a pic:
[image: 2 squares overlapping, making the common line thicker]

Comment: It is not thicker, it is darker. Incidentally, you understand that a line cannot be thinner than 1 pixel, right? The "thickness" of 0.1 is achieved by making the line look paler.

Answer (score 3):

The shared segment is not thicker, it is darker. A line cannot be thinner than 1 pixel. The "thickness" of 0.1 is achieved by making the line look paler.

Having said that, you can avoid the "thickening" of the common edge by not drawing it twice:

```
plt.plot(x1, y, 'k', linewidth = 0.1)
plt.plot(x2[:-1], y[:-1], 'k', linewidth = 0.1)
```

Comment: Well my example is very simplified, but I actually have big polygons (country boundaries) overlapping eachother at some edges. So I guess I'll have to find the common edges and plot them only once.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in **antialiasing**.

See, I changed colors and line widths, so

```
plt.plot(x1, y, 'r', linewidth = 5)
plt.plot(x2, y, 'g', linewidth = 5)
```

gives

[image]

As you may see, the green line of the second “square” *completely overwrites the red one*, not increasing the width of the common line.

So the problem is not in matplotlib, but in displaying so narrow lines in the way you wanted, because they are *antialiased* — you may see it if you zoom in my picture. For instance the upper left corner:

[image]